# getelementbyid().click not working

Tags: javascript

I am making a website that whenever I click and x is equal to a range of numbers, it plays audio, but after i click once when x is between those numbers, i will also play if x is not in the range. Please Help. Here is my code. by the way, i will not use jquery because it does not work on chrome.

```
    if(x<=1200&&x>=600){
    var n=true;
    };
    if(x<=1200&&x>=600&&n==true){
    document.getElementById('a').onclick = function(){
    audio.play();
    n=false;    
        }
    }
    else{n=false}
```

Comment: What do you mean JQuery doesn't work on Chrome?

Comment: Further to millerbr's comment: jQuery works perfectly well on chrome. It's not necessary, by any means, but it certainly works.

Comment: @AMACB, why does it matter - OP says the audio is playing, even more than needed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code does is that it adds a click event listener on that element, and afterwards the click handler will trigger regardless of your x value because you don't have any checks **inside** the click handler.

The solution is to do create the click listener only once, and check for the value of `x` inside it. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById('a').onclick = function(){
  if(x <= 1200 && x >= 600 && n == true) {
    audio.play();
    n = false;    
  }
}
```

---

See this (I've replaced audio playing with div highlighting, but it's the same principle):

```js
var r = document.getElementById('r');
var n = true;
var x = 1000;
document.getElementById('a').onclick = function(){
  if(x <= 1200 && x >= 600 && n == true) {
    r.className = 'playing';
    n = false;
    printN();
    setTimeout(function(){
      r.className = '';
    }, 2000);
  }
}

function toggleN(){n = !n;printN()}
function printN(){document.getElementById('n').textContent = 'n is set to ' + n;}
function randomizeX(){x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200);printX()}
function printX(){document.getElementById('x').textContent = 'x equals ' + x;}
```

```css
#r {display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #ccc; transition: background 1s linear;}
#r.playing {background: green}
```

```html
<button id="a">Hit me</button><br><br>
<div id="r"></div>
<p id="x">x equals 1000</p>
<p id="n">n is set to true</p>
<button onclick="toggleN()">Toggle n</button>
<button onclick="randomizeX()">Randomize x</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do but here a guest :

```
if(x<=1200&&x>=600){
    var n=true;
    var clicked = false;
    };
    if(x<=1200&&x>=600&&n==true || clicked==true){
    document.getElementById('a').onclick = function(){
    audio.play();
    n=false;
    clicked = true;
        }
    }
    else{
        n=false;
        clicked = false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want, if i understood you correctly.

no reason to check x several times + check n, since n is only true if x is between your ranges.

```
var ab =  document.getElementById('a');
var n = false;

if( x <= 1200 && x >= 600 ){
  n = true; //If x is within range.
} else {
  n = false; //Reset when x goes out of range.
}

ab.onclick = function(){
  if(n){
    audio.play();
  }
}
```

Note: If a user clicks the button several times, 
the audio plays several times.
This can be fixed by adding another variable checking if a user already clicked once, 
Since i don't know your setup, i.e. should users be able to click to play the audio several times in a row(when it finish playing once), i can't supply you with a solution for that without knowing.